# Putting blank or NULL value in SELECT-OPTIONS HIGH value of DEC field?

Tags: null, range, abap

Is there any possible way to fill one of range scopes in SELECT-OPTION with blank value like ' ', or just '', except from default 0?

I have this piece of code in ABAP:

```
data: gv_verzn type verzn
SELECT-OPTIONS s_verzn FOR gv_verzn NO INTERVALS OBLIGATORY.

....

s_verzn-sign = 'I'.
s_verzn-option = 'BT'.
s_verzn-low = iv_val.
s_verzn-high = ''.         "<----here I want to have blank value instead of zero
```

On a picture I show you actual result with unnecessery zeros.[image]

@EDIT1:
[image]

Comment: There is no `null` value in ABAP, only `INITIAL`. ABAP lacks this concept. What exactly does your screenshot show? Is it the debugger view of `s_verzn`? Or is is the result of a SELECT query? If so, please share your query, too.

Comment: Screenshot shows result of automatic filling fields with ABAP code which i post above. 's_verzn-low' means lower range value, in this example that are values: -99999, 1, 31, 61, 91, 181, 361 like on screenshot. 's_verzn-high' is upper range value which I want to keep emtpy (initial).

Comment: `verzn` is a `DEC` datatype, length 5. It's initial value is therefore 0.

Comment: in case of BETWEEN by SELECT-OPTIONS (respectively ranges) you have to have values in low and high field as well. The high value also has to be higher than the low value. So, filling the high field with zero, while having a positive value in the low field does not make much sense...

Comment: I put verzn definition in edit of post. But I see it now, its DEC so it can't be blank .

Comment: In theory, you can show blank instead of zero even if it's a DEC field (or any numeric field), by defining a new data element with a custom **conversion exit** (that will reflect also in lower field).

Comment: Don't you mean using `EQ` (one value corresponding to low, high being ignored) instead of `BT` (interval between low and high vlaues)?

Comment: @SandraRossi but a conversion exit wouldn't change the outcome if the select option is used, e.g. in a SELECT query?

Comment: @konstantin A conversion exit is just used to change the display, not the internal value (ABAP code in both directions).

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes, I mean `BT`, because sometimes, optionally I want to select a range of values instead on single value. I have to modify a program that previously used `EQ`, and what I wanted to do was if there is **high** range blank, then program should behave like old one, and if **high** isn't blank then program had to use some new feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verzn` is a signed `DEC` datatype, with length 5 plus 1 character for the sign.

Add this line to your coding:

```
IF s_verzn-high is initial.
  s_verzn-high = 99999.
ENDIF.
```

Maybe there's an ABAP command for the maximum value of a given datatype which you could use.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear for me now. It can't be blank because it's DEC data type. Thanks !